# How to transpose row in panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have this table here and I want to make "Daily ICU occupancy" as a column with the value under as a row. Same for "Daily hospital occupancy".
How do I do that? I was thinking to create a new data frame having only "Daily ICU occupancy", same for Daily hospital occupancy" and then merging both data frame in one. However, it does not seem like the best approach. I am sure have a better way to do this.

```
entity       iso_code       date                 indicator           value
127422  United States      USA 2020-07-15       Daily ICU occupancy   9245.0
127424  United States      USA 2020-07-15  Daily hospital occupancy  33759.0
127426  United States      USA 2020-07-16       Daily ICU occupancy   9797.0
127428  United States      USA 2020-07-16  Daily hospital occupancy  38537.0
127430  United States      USA 2020-07-17       Daily ICU occupancy  10700.0
```

Update:
Just to be more clear what I am looking for. I want my new data table to be like this

```
entity       iso_code       date                Daily ICU occupancy Daily hospital occupancy                   
127422  United States      USA 2020-07-15          9245.0             33759.0
127426  United States      USA 2020-07-16          9797.0             38537.0 
127430  United States      USA 2020-07-17          10700.0            38600.0
```

Comment: Have a read through [the "reshaping" part of the Pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html), that may have what you want.

Comment: What would you expect the final output to look like given there's entity and iso_code columns there... It might be you're just after `df.pivot('date', 'indicator', 'value')` if you don't need to retain those in some way.

Comment: Looks like could want: `df.pivot(index=['entity', 'iso_code', 'date'], columns='indicator', values='value')`, however given the different 'entity" values, this will keep two separate rows, you need to give more details

Answer (score 0):

you can try using pivot to achieve this. modify the below code

```
df.pivot_table(index=['entity','iso_code'], columns='indicator',
                     values='value').reset_index()
```

Note my answer is based on formatting issues when copying to clipboard. do adjust to suit your use case

```
indicator   entity  iso_code    ICU occupancy   hospital occupancy
0   2020-07-15  Daily   9245.0  33759.0
1   2020-07-16  Daily   9797.0  38537.0
2   2020-07-17  Daily   10700.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entity':[127422, 127424, 127426, 127428, 127430],
    'iso_code':['United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'United States'], 
    'date':['USA 2020-07-15', 'USA 2020-07-15', 'USA 2020-07-16', 'USA 2020-07-16', 'USA 2020-07-17'],
    'indicator':['Daily ICU occupancy', 'Daily hospital occupancy', 'Daily ICU occupancy', 'Daily hospital occupancy', 'Daily ICU occupancy'],
    'value':[9245.0, 33759.0, 9797.0, 38537.0, 10700.0]
})

print(df)

   entity       iso_code            date                 indicator    value
0  127422  United States  USA 2020-07-15       Daily ICU occupancy   9245.0
1  127424  United States  USA 2020-07-15  Daily hospital occupancy  33759.0
2  127426  United States  USA 2020-07-16       Daily ICU occupancy   9797.0
3  127428  United States  USA 2020-07-16  Daily hospital occupancy  38537.0
4  127430  United States  USA 2020-07-17       Daily ICU occupancy  10700.0
```

```
df = df.pivot(index=['iso_code', 'date'], columns='indicator', values='value').reset_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)

indicator       iso_code            date  Daily ICU occupancy  \
0          United States  USA 2020-07-15               9245.0   
1          United States  USA 2020-07-16               9797.0   
2          United States  USA 2020-07-17              10700.0   

indicator  Daily hospital occupancy  
0                           33759.0  
1                           38537.0  
2                               NaN
```

[image]